# How to access outer scope variables from a function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, scope, plpgsql

I have this code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    NODE_ID bigint :=  46;
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funk(VAL bigint) 
    RETURNS bigint AS $f$
        BEGIN
            RETURN VAL;
        END; $f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    RAISE NOTICE '%', funk(NODE_ID);
END $$;
```

I works as expected and prints 46 to the console.
I want to get rid of the parameters, because the variable is global. But I am getting errors:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    NODE_ID bigint :=  46;
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funk() 
    RETURNS bigint AS $f$
        BEGIN
            RETURN NODE_ID;
        END; $f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    RAISE NOTICE '%', funk();
END $$;
```

I'm getting "NODE_ID not exist". Is there a way to access the outer variable in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work, because the function has no connection to your `DO` block whatsoever. It is a persistent database object that will continue to exist in the database after the `DO` block has finished.

In essence, a function is just a string with the function body (and some metadata, see `pg_proc`); in this case, the function body consists of the text between the opening and the closing `$f$`. It is interpreted by the language handler when the function is run.

The only database data you can reference in a function are other persistent database objects, and a variable in a `DO` block isn't one of those.

There are no global variables in PostgreSQL except for – in a way – the configuration parameters. You can access these with the `SET` and `SHOW` SQL commands and, more conveniently in code, with the `set_config` and `current_setting` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Or use dynamic SQL:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    NODE_ID bigint :=  46;
    src text := format('
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funk() 
        RETURNS bigint AS $f$
            BEGIN
                RETURN %s;
            END; 
        $f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    ', NODE_ID::text);
BEGIN
    execute src;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', funk();
END $$;
```

(works for me, landing on your question searching for solution of same problem)