# Accessing outer block variables from within a nested block

Tags: postgresql, variables, scope, nested, plpgsql

I am trying to access a variable from a parent block from within a nested block using postgresql's plpgsql as follows

```
DO $outer-block$
DECLARE
  test_variable text DEFAULT "test";
BEGIN

  DO $inner-block$
  BEGIN

    RAISE NOTICE '%',test_variable;

  END;
  $inner-block$;

END;
$outer-block$;
```

When I try to run this, it tells me that "the column test_variable doesn't exist", so I suppose that this variable is not in scope when the inner block is given control, is there any way to access it from within the nested block?

(I checked up this question: [How to access outer scope variables from a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457985/how-to-access-outer-scope-variables-from-a-function-in-postgresql), which was sort of similar, but in that case it's trying to access the outer block variable from whitin a function, which is a persistent database object, and it would in a way be trying to create a closure, that is not what I am doing here, since I want to access the outer block's scope from within a one-time execution inner block, which might make a difference, but I don't know it for certain)

Comment: The inner DO blocks makes absolutely no sense to me. What are you trying to achieve with that? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm trying to group specific sub tasks into smaller named blocks with a defined purpose to structure and organize the entire logic, be able to read the whole thing more easily when I go back to it later, creating functions for these one-time tasks wouldn't be worth it. If you have better suggestions for structuring the code, those are welcome, but I would still like to know if what I'm trying to do is possible, regardless of wether it is or not the best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) shows you how to do this. Using your example as starting point:

```
DO
$$
<<outerblock>>
DECLARE
  test_variable text DEFAULT 'test';
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%',test_variable;

    DECLARE
        test_variable text := 'inner test';
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE '%',test_variable;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', outerblock.test_variable;

  END;

END;
$$;

NOTICE:  test
NOTICE:  inner test
NOTICE:  test
```

Differences from your example:

1. 'test' instead of "test" so the value is not seen as an identifier.
2. Using the `<<outerblock>>` label syntax to label the outer block. The `$<some_tag>$` does not do this.
3. Using the label in `outerblock.test_variable` to fetch the variable value from the outer block.

FYI, in your original example there is no need for the inner block as you don't do anything that changes the value `test_variable` so it will be the same as the outer block anyway.

**UPDATE**

Just realized you maybe trying to do nested functions, per the use of `DO` in your example. That is a different thing then blocks. In order to pass data you would have to add it as a parameter to an argument in the nested function. Since `DO` functions can't have arguments that is not going to work. You would have to use a regular function.

**FURTHER UPDATE**

You can have a nested `DO` function:

```
DO
$$
<<outerblock>>
DECLARE
  test_variable text DEFAULT 'test';
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%',test_variable;

    DO
    $i$
    DECLARE
        inner_test_variable text := 'inner test';
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Inner %', inner_test_variable;

    END;
    $i$;
END;
$$;

NOTICE:  test
NOTICE:  Inner inner test
DO
```

You just can't access the variables in the outer portion. They would have to be passed into the inner function as a parameter to a function argument and `DO` functions do not have arguments. You could do it with a regular function.

Comment: I don't see the inner block's "DO", did you forget to type it or are you doing something here that eludes me, I see you did type "DECLARE" and 'BEGIN' twice though

Comment: There is no need for the `DO`.

Comment: See my UPDATE for more.

Comment: I am not trying to do nested functions, I really am trying to just have nested blocks, and in fact I am trying to put them inside a function just like in the link you provided, I didn't know the DO for the inner block was unnecessary, thanks this lets me do exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Glad it worked. Another FYI, per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) I would stay away from using `-` as in `outer-block` and `inner-block`. Use `_` instead. Using `-` means you have to quote the identifier when you create it and whenever you use it.

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in ming. Also I must point out something I just found out, it's not that "there is no need for the DO" of the inner block, but actually, for some reason it is necessary NOT to have it, otherwise it gives me an error, but if I don't put the inner block's "DO", then the whole thing works fine. I can put a <<label>> for the inner block even if I skip putting in the word "DO" for it either way, so that's cool

Comment: Actually you can have a nested `DO`, see the FURTHER UPDATE to the answer.

Comment: Oh my bad, I explained it poorly, you can have a nested ```DO``` and it will work (that's what I was doing initially), but what I meant is that when you add the ```DO``` to the inner block, for some reason you can't access the variables from the outer block anymore the way you explained, since it throws an error when you try to, but if you don't add the ```DO``` to the inner block, then it works fine

Comment: One more time. `DO` is an anonymous function, it is it's own entity and does not have access to the function it is embedded in. The only way you can pass information from the outer function to the inner one is by passing it in via the inner functions arguments. Since `DO` functions don't have arguments that is not going to happen. If you used a regular function you could do something like `some_func(some_arg varchar)` and then `some_fnc(test_variable)` and use the `test_variable` in `some_fnc()`. Assuming `some_fnc()` had a return then you pass that back to the outer function.